# How does Facebook (or how would you) partition an incredibly large database of friends?

Tags: database

How would you store 10 billion friends where a friend can be anyone's friend? The simplest solution is to create a database, a table called *Person* and create a many-to-many association between *Person* and *Person*.

But this would not scale properly. This data would need to be partitioned across many databases around the world so the load can be properly distributed.

As a software developer who's kind new to database development, I'm curious how the SO community would solve this problem.

Comment: There's a whole science field around this question :-) Personally, I like this site http://highscalability.com/. They explore this question often and publish white papers about facebook, twitter, Plenty of Fish and other High Traffic Sites with large databases. At the end it's really a combination of Software and Hardware Architecture.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely they don't use a relational database to store this information.  It's more likely some flavor of NoSQL, possibly a [Graph Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph%5fdatabase).

It's possible there are blogs (from facebook or third parties) that discuss how it is *actually* done--the above is just my own speculation based on a basic understanding of these kinds of data stores.

Comment: This video briefly explains how a Graph Database can solve my given problem: http://player.vimeo.com/video/56040747#t=7m